# Chaining python dictionaries to make a new one

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two python dictionaries, say,

```
d1 = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':'v2', 'k3':'v3'}
d2 = {'v1':'w1','v2':'w2','v5':'w5'}
```

what I need is a merged dict like this -

```
mergeDict= {k1:(v1,w1), k2:(v2,w2), k3:(v3)}
```

Whatever I have been able to look up or read has dealt with appending dictionaries, nothing like this. I called this chaining since value of first dict is potentially the key in second dict.

So far i have done this through typical loop and lookup on keys(). Wondering if there is a more pythonic way to achieve this that i might be missing here ?

Comment: Is `d2 = {v1:w1,v2:w2,v5:w5}` supposed to be `d2 = {k1:w1,k2:w2}`? Otherwise, how does `v1` as a key become `k1`?

Comment: You might want to look into getting a multidict library. There is no standard lib implementation of it in python

Comment: @dawg the whole idea of the question is that the value in first dict can act as a key in second dict. thats why you see k1,v1 in first and v1,w1 in second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dict comprehension seems to work:

```
out = {k: (v, d2[v]) if v in d2 else (v,) for k,v in d1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'k1': ('v1', 'w1'), 'k2': ('v2', 'w2'), 'k3': ('v3',)}
```

Comment: Very close to what i have written myself.  any better than this ?

Comment: @Raghav how do you define "better"?

Comment: Well, I m relatively new to hands on python coding, so, wondering if there is a more "pythonic" way than this..

Comment: @Raghav comprehensions are the most pythonic imo.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to merge values with the same key into a collection, you could

- create a new dict
- use `itertools` to iterate over any number of dicts
- some default value you can pack into (such as a list or set)

```py
import itertools

d3 = {}
for key, value in itertools.chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
    d3.get(key)
    try:
        d3[key].append(value)  # add value to list
    except KeyError:           # first instance of key
        d3[key] = [value]      # start a fresh list
```

Note, this doesn't meet the question as-written, which is trying to pack keys matching the same *value* in another dict, but share the keys between 'em

```py
>>> d1 = {"k1":"v1","k2":"v2","k3":"v3"}
>>> d2 = {"v1":"w1","v2":"w2","v5":"w5"}
[..]
>>> d3
{'k1': ['v1'], 'k2': ['v2'], 'k3': ['v3'], 'v1': ['w1'], 'v2': ['w2'], 'v5': ['w5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets and dict update with Python 3.9+

```
>>> {k:(d1[k],) for k in d1} | {k:(d1[k],d2[k]) for k in set(d1) & set(d2)} 
{'k1': ('v1', 'w1'), 'k2': ('v2', 'w2'), 'k3': ('v3',)}
```